# why can I see wordpress site directories & files in browser?

Tags: wordpress, apache, directory, root

I installed WP locally on XAMPP.
When I manually type my project root in a browser I start seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxDcJ.png). But when I run the project through VScode Live server I start seeing all files and directories of my site see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXhvM.png).

Why does this happen? Is it because I run the project locally? Or is it because the root is followed by :5050 port number?

My theme style.css is empty.
My theme index.php contains only starting html !+tab attributes (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkSzY.png))

Answer (score 0):

The first image looks like to be served by apache which loads mod_php which "executes" the php code of every .php file and serve the result as html.

The second image looks like an application running on port 5000 (which might not be apache) and NOT using a module to "execute" .php file so it just shows the content of the folder.